# Django-allauth 0.8.1 Twitter integration

Tags: django-allauth

I am using Django-allauth , i have enabled social network logins, google,facebook and twitter, For some reason twitter is not working,

Configurations

**Settings.py (shortened)**

```
DEBUG = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL="ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED"

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount"
)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    )

INSTALLED_APPS = (  
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',

)

# Social login
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    { 'facebook':
        { 'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
          'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate' },
          'METHOD': 'js_sdk'},

    'google':
        { 'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
          'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' } }  

}


# django-allauth settings
EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION=False
ACCOUNT_USER_DISPLAY=lambda user: user.profile
```

**urls.py (shortened)**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), 
)
```

**Twitter app settings**

**http://my_domain.com/accounts/twitter/login/callback/**

**consumer key** and **consumer secret**  are also configured on /admin/socialaccount/socialapp/

Version:
django-allauth==0.8.1

When i click on Twitter button on login screen, all i am getting is a page with title "Social Network Login Failure" ,no debug screen, i am able to login using google or facebook.

This is url on the page : http://my_domain.com/accounts/twitter/login/callback/?oauth_token=leC3t4BYr9KVAyW22ixxxxxxyVyOHiqaUnIhXwoyRM&oauth_verifier=WdDAwxpxxxxxMzWAr5tcx3mUfZ63304fsxxxx16qKM

Comment: I tried latest django-allauth in a fresh django project and everything works fine. So this could probably be version inconsistency between,

Django==1.4.1
django-allauth==0.8.1
python 2.6 (and 2.7.3)

Comment: Errors got from manually raising the error in views.py line 84 https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/views.py#L84

OAuthError at /accounts/twitter/login/callback/
No access to private resources at "api.twitter.com".
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/twitter/login/callback/?oauth_token=sJ1VbozWsHPPMPHHr5xxxSly5vxxxxoauth_verifier=7EkHIxxxxxUsooYqS9HHHTTAFJkExxxxxx4sMUZQGY
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: OAuthError
Exception Value: 
No access to private resources at "api.twitter.com".
Python Version: 2.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option is to update allauth to 0.8.3 or newer :)

After hours of debugging and frustration , i finally had my answer.

Twitter updated their API few months ago, so its not compatible with allauth == 0.8.1 anymore.

*allauth.socialaccount.providers.views.py* Line - 17

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json'
```

this should be

```
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
```